# Можно ли в selenium(+python) получить код страницы не открытой в данной момент в браузере?

Tags: python, selenium

Хотел бы такой сценарий:

-Я авторизовался на тестовом сайте, который довольно таки большой

-Сделал кой-чего...

А теперь вопрос:

После этих действий мне бы хотелось проверить изменения на нескольких страницах сайта.
Было круто не открывать эти страницы, а просто на фоне быстренько обежать, забрать код, распарсить найти или не найти изменения не покидая целевой страницы. Типо как реквестсом и бьютифул супом. Мне кажется так будет гораздо быстрее и надёжнее.(часть можно через бд конеш, но все таки интересно найти именно такой способ.)

Как я понял "browser.page_source" работает только на текущей странице.

Может js какой кинуть можно?

Или это вообще бессмысленно?

Comment: Чем не устраивает получение через тот же `requests`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Там весь контент для авторизованного пользователя. А авторизовываться через requests врядли получится.

Comment: @СергейПопков Вы можете в requests открыть сессию и внутри нее аторизоваться, дальнейшая работа уже будет от лица авторизованного пользователя.

Comment: Либо авторизационные куки/заголовки из селениума в requests прокинуть.

Comment: @asanisimov@МихаилМуругов 
Ура, у меня получилось, в порядке сначала селениум потом реквестс.
Я не силён в таких вопросах, про куки, мне вот теперь интересно.
Я значит авторизовался, и забираю куки "browser.get_cookies()", почему то по итогу получается один список с друмя(!) словарями, и только со вторым словарём все получается. 
Так и должно быть или просто зависит от сайта? Для чего первый тогда? 
И еще, я могу сохранить эти данные и всегда по ним заходить, или они портятся, и надо каждый раз пересобирать?

Comment: @СергейПопков Куки, обычно, со временем протухают. Почему несколько словарей в списке - кука это не просто `ключ: значение`, они имеют срок жизни, домен и тд. Каждый словарь списка содержит в себе полную информацию о каждой куке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оч помогли комментарии, но раз никто не отвечает, скину тестовый код не придирайтесь особо, лень редактировать:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 '
} #вроде как это нужно по инструкции, но получается из без этого 

def test_tet(browser, main_url):
   ttt = BasePage(browser)
   ttt.open(main_url)
   d = browser.get_cookies()[1] #не знаю почему, но работает только со вторым словарём
   s = requests.Session() #создаю сессию
   s.cookies.set(domain=d['domain'], name=d['name'], path=d['path'], value=d['value']) #подкидываю куки
  

   email = browser.find_element(By.ID, "Email")
   email.send_keys('test@user.ru')
   password = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'PasswordUser')
   password.send_keys('1qaz@WSX')
   browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type="submit"]').click() 
   #здесь авторизуюсь

   r = s.get(main_url + "/systemparameter", headers=headers)
    #теперь можно забирать любую страницу сайта не открывая её в браузере
   with open('site.html', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(r.text.encode('utf8'))
```